# execute something after callback has been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute a function after a callback has been executed.

here is my example

```
var callback1 = function () {
  // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
};
var callback2 = function () {
 // make other things after callback1 has finished
};

$("input[type='text']").change(callback1);
```

Then when the callback1 has been executed I would like to execute the callback2.
What is the proper way to do this by using jquery/javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anonymous function and include both callbacks in there.

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function(){ 
  callback1();
  callback2();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do like below:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    callback1();
    callback2();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign multiple callbacks like so:

```
$('input ...')
    .on('change', callback1)
    .on('change', callback2)
```

There's one difference with how the other answers are written (i.e. use anonymous function that runs both callbacks iteratively). Consider this code:

```
function callback1(evt) {
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here

    // stop any other handlers from running
    evt.stopPropagation();
}

function callback2() {
    // make other things after callback1 has finished
}
```

You can prevent the execution of `callback2` from inside `callback1` by calling `evt.stopPropagation()` (I think returning `false` would accomplish the same thing). This is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `callback2` at the end of `callback1`:

```
var callback1 = function () {
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
    callback2();
};
var callback2 = function () {
    // make other things after callback1 has finished
};

$("input[type='text']").change(callback1);
```

Or if you'd like to keep them completely independent, you can pass a function to the `change()` event which calls the callbacks individually:

```
var callback1 = function () { /* code */ };
var callback2 = function () { /* code */ };
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    callback1();
    callback2();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the two callback functions in another anonymous function:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    callback1;
    callback2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a unique callback executing both the cb1 and cb2 code.
2. Call the cb2 from inside the cb1.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this:

```
var callback1 = function () {
  // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
};
var callback2 = function () {
 // make other things after callback1 has finished
};
$('input[type="text"]').change(function() {
    callback1();
    callback2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function that returns a function to do.

```
var callback1 = function (my_callback) {
  return function(){
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
    //   ...
    my_callback();
  }
};
var callback2 = function () {
 // make other things after callback1 has finished
};

$("input[type='text']").change(callback1(callback2));
```